# How do I define a Main method in a Class versus a Module?

Tags: vb.net, class, module

I was just practicing some coding and noticed that I was able to use class instead of Module in VB .NET. So I replaced my module to class and I got this error message:

> No accessible 'Main' method with an appropriate signature was found in 'practicevb'.practicevb

I made sure that the startup object was set correctly in `Properties > Application > Startup Objects`.

The error message disappears if I change it back to Module but I would like to keep it class since the other parts of my code I changed to class and didn't return and error messages.

```
Class Atic

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, this proram will calcaulate the quadratic forumla ax^2 + bx + c")
        Dim Quads As New Quads
        Quads.Calc()

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Ok cool thanks for all the info. What NoAlias suggested works. I think I'll keep it as Module since it sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My guess is that your application is a command line application.  Make the class Public and Shared...

```
Public Shared Sub Main()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

For any future reader, if your `Main()` is in a **Module** (not Class Module) and you're still getting this error, make sure the method does not take any parameters. Unlike C++, VB.NET doesn't take command-line arguments as a Main method's parameters. Instead you should define a zero-parameter Main() method and use `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` to access the supplied parameters. I banged head for some time before I realized this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are **NEW** to Classes

Classes is a different concept than a `module` module is a collection of functions , but `class` is a template which should be instantiating an object and use.

First go though the OOP basics in VB.NET [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/OOPS_In_VBNET.aspx)

If your are a **Pro**

Use `Shared Sub Main()` ...

Answer (score 1):

[Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da%28VS.100%29.aspx) are just classes where all members are shared (static in C#).

If you want to change a module into a class, just add the `Shared` modifier to its members:

```
Shared Sub Main() ...
```

Although, I really think [modules are a good idea](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-static-classes-are-not-real-classes.html) and a perfect place to put your `Main` function.

Comment: i think he is get confused with hardcore OOP in C#  ! :-)

Comment: i think he is new to programming in `OOP` so i just wonder stuff like `(static in C#).`  will confuse him :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Main method is required as the entry point of your applications. I needs to be calleable without instantiating an object as there is no way of doing this before your program starts.

Either just make this method and the class static as has bene said, or better have a module just for this entry point, then instantiate an object and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `Public Sub Main` procedure for your project. Declare it as `Shared` if and only if you define it inside a class.